# Amazon AWS custom java app billing vs web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any difference for billing if application on AWS is web java application that communicate with outside world through web service or servlet or is i.e console java application with opened socket server and someone outside is connecting to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all things are equal then the short answer is: **No - there is no difference**.

AWS bills you based on resource usage, so a web service, servlet or console application will still require an EC2 instance to run on. Assuming they can all run on a given instance type (e.g. micro) then you'll be billed at the hourly rate of the EC2 instance type.

If you wanted to get pedantic, then the solution that would send the least amount of data out would be the cheapest. When considering this remember that it doesn't matter if you connect in, or it connects to you, what matters is the number of bytes transmitted out from your instance. So a solution that support compression of the transmitted data would be better than a solution that didn't.